# Why does having a copy constructor cause this code to break?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So I have this code:

```
template<class T>
struct IntegerType
{
    T value;

    //Next line causes errors
    //constexpr IntegerType(IntegerType& value) : value(value.value) { }
    constexpr IntegerType(T value) : value(value) { }
};
template<class int_t>
class FullMult{
    int_t value;
    int_t carry;
    public:

    constexpr FullMult() : value(0), carry(0) { }
    constexpr FullMult(const int_t& value, const int_t& carry) : value(value), carry(carry) { }

};

int main()
{
    FullMult<IntegerType<unsigned int> > thing 
        = FullMult<IntegerType<unsigned int> >(
            IntegerType<unsigned int>(12),IntegerType<unsigned int>(12));
}
```

But when I try to add a copy constructor to the type `IntegerType` by uncommenting the line `constexpr IntegerType(IntegerType& value) : value(value.value) { }`  the code breaks and tells me that I am trying to use the copy constructor of the `FullMult` type:

```
use of deleted function 'FullMult<IntegerType<unsigned int> >::FullMult(FullMult<IntegerType<unsigned int> >&&)'
```

This is the code that gives me the error:

```
template<class T>
struct IntegerType
{
    T value;

    //Next line causes errors
    constexpr IntegerType(IntegerType& value) : value(value.value) { }
    constexpr IntegerType(T value) : value(value) { }
};
template<class int_t>
class FullMult{
    int_t value;
    int_t carry;
    public:

    constexpr FullMult() : value(0), carry(0) { }
    constexpr FullMult(const int_t& value, const int_t& carry) : value(value), carry(carry) { }

};

int main()
{
    FullMult<IntegerType<unsigned int> > thing 
        = FullMult<IntegerType<unsigned int> >(
            IntegerType<unsigned int>(12),IntegerType<unsigned int>(12));
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Do you use one class as a template parameter for the other?

Comment: The code in the question should be the broken code, not the working code. Please clearly and unambiguously post a MCVE showing the problem

Comment: @Kupto Yes.....

Comment: @M.M.  If you uncomment the line after it says "the next line causes errors" the errors happen

Comment: @DarthRubik 1. The idea is that *you* uncomment the relevant line. 2. No links to code here please. 3. That's a pretty poor way to write a copy constructor. It should be something like `//constexpr IntegerType(const IntegerType& that) : value(that.value) { }`.

Comment: You are passing a literal.  Adding `const` to the parameter fixes the error.  Your error is basically no different than [this one](http://ideone.com/QxUTJ3)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But why does it tell me that I am using the copy constructor of the `FullMult` type?

Comment: Because you *are* using the copy constructor of `FullMult`.  Look carefully at that line in `main`.  Again, look at a simple case:  `foo thing = foo(12);`  That is what that line boils down to, and with my eyes, that's a copy constructor being invoked.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right, there are two problems. Will edit my answer!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I cannot believe that I did not see that....thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is on the line:

```
constexpr FullMult(const int_t& value, const int_t& carry) : value(value), carry(carry)
```

You initialize the class member `int_t value;` with an argument of type `const int_t`.  However there is no matching constructor. The `IntegerType` copy-constructor accepts a non-const reference and that cannot be bound to `const int_t`.

However, even if you fix this line independently, there is a second problem, the one that shows up in your error message.  The code (abbreviated for clarity):

```
F thing = F(...bla...);
```

invokes the move-constructor of `F`. Or at least, it performs a copy/move accssibility check even if the operation is elided.  But as shown in the error message, `F(F&&)` is deleted.  This is because the default definition would be:

```
F(F&& other): value(std::move(other.value)), carry(std::move(other.carry)) {}
```

But `IntegerType` has no matching constructor -- the copy-constructor taking non-const lvalue reference does not bind to the xvalue `std::move(other.value)`.

---

Both of these problems can be fixed by making the `IntegerType` copy constructor accept a const reference.

Alternatively, the second problem could be fixed by giving `IntegerType` a move-constructor in addition to the copy-constructor. (But the first problem would remain).

Comment: NB. Using gcc or clang on godbolt as provided by your link, I got a pile of diagnostics that indicated the problem.

Comment: You beat me to it... To use a scoop from my unfinished answer, try: `constexpr IntegerType(const IntegerType& value) : value(value.value) { }`